# Value error when defining a new array

Tags: python, arrays

I do research on cosmology and recently I had a chance to gain experience on numerical simulations.

I have experience on C++, but I have just started using python.

The following is part of the python code I am currently writing.

```
def energy(s):
    def spectrum(s):
        phi = sol[s,:]
        N = len(phi)
        return 2.0 / N * np.real(np.fft.rfft(phi))
    delta_t = t_array[1] - t_array[0]
    sp = spectrum(s)
    spb = spectrum(s-1)
    spa = spectrum(s+1)
    L = len(sp)
    def spectrum_dot(s):
        sD = np.array([]).reshape(1,L)
        for j in range(0,L):
         sD[j] = (spa[j] - spb[j]) / (2 * delta_t)
        return sD
    sd = spectrum_dot(s)
    E = np.array([]).reshape(1,L)
    for i in range(0,L):
     E[i] = (sd[i]*sd[i]/2) + (sp[i]*sp[i]*(i*math.pi/128)*(i*math.pi/128)/2) + V(sp[i])
    return E

f_l = energy(time_steps * 128 / 619)
plt.plot(f_l[1:200])
plt.axhline(0,color='black',linewidth=0.6)
plt.axis([0,200,-1,1])
plt.savefig('128.png')
```

For the line "sD = np.array([]).reshape(1,L)", I am getting an ValueError that says "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged".

Defining the return array of "spectrum_dot(s)" seems to be the problem.

Could you give me a hint to correct this error?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please make sure you correctly transcribe your indentation when posting python code. Badly indented python code is nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for the point-out. I have corrected the indentation.

Comment: You're trying to reshape an empty array. The original array has shape (0,), so you won't be able to shape it into something of length `L`, hence the error. Something like `np.array([0] * L).reshape(1, L)` would work, or better, np.zeros((1, 3))

Comment: @JCVanHamme Thank you for the reply. What I am trying to do is declare a 1 dimensional array "sD" with length L, and define the L element of the array "sD" using 'for' loop. With your solution, the error is removed. But am I using a right method to define the elements of "sD"?

Comment: If you're just creating an empty array to store data in, I'd use the `np.zeros` function over the way you're doing it. And I'd expect `np.zeros(L)` would be sufficient for what you'd need.

Comment: Using `numpy` you don't need to dimension every array that you're going to use, in particular the value of an array expression is another array, and you can assign a new name to this newly computed value… I mean that in place of your loop to fill a void `sD` array you can simply write `sD = (spa-spb)/(2*delta_t)` — no initialization, no loop, no indices, just a vector expression and an assignment.

Comment: @JCVanHamme Thank you. It seems to be the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, the first is that the `.reshape()` method cannot change the *size* of an array (or the data that the array addresses) but only the *shape* of that data

```
# legal
z1 = np.zeros(20) 
z1.reshape((4,5))
# illegal
z1.reshape((5,5))
```

The other problem is the fortran/c background that I also have, so I can understand your problems... When you use `numpy` you can avoid, you **should** avoid, writing loops that modify term by term an array, but rather write *vector expressions*, whose value is another array that you can later reuse if you assign a name to it, going back to your code

```
sD = (sda-sdb)/2/delta_t
```

no initialization of `sD`, no indices, no explicit loop and, most important, **the implicit loop is executed with velocity comparable to a compiled language**, i.e., order of magnitudes faster than an explicit loop in Python.

The rules that `numpy` follows when dealing with array expressions are known as *broadcasting rules* and if you're going to use seriously this library you have to familiarize yourself with *broadcasting* that enables you to write (sometimes a little bit arcane, even if this was not the case in our example) expressions that avoid you the overload of explicit loops.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation.